# Checking soduku in C, why my code doesn't work?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, sudoku

I am building a program to check soduku solutions in C, where the user inserts the size of the puzzle and the solution. 
The program needs to check whether the solution is valid or not using only 2d arrays.

My algorithm is to take every row, column, and box, put it in a 1d arrray (each), sort it and compare it to another 1d array going from 1-n.

I don't know why, but my program doesn't work and I need help.

My code:

```
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Include files:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


/*=========================================================================
  Constants and definitions:
==========================================================================*/

/* put your #defines and typedefs here*/
void printOpenMessageForSodokoSize();
void printOpenMessageForSodokoSolution();
void printValidSolution();
void printBadSolution();
int root(int a);
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n);
int compareTo(int arr[], int n);
int checkRows(int n,  int mat[][n]);
int checkColumns(int n, int mat[][n]);
int checkGrids(int n, int mat[][n], int sRow, int sCol);

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  The main program. (describe what your program does here)
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    printOpenMessageForSodokoSize();
    int n;
    int grids=1, rows=1, cols=1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(root(n)<=0)
        scanf("%d", &n);
    printOpenMessageForSodokoSolution();
    int mat[n][n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    while(grids) //checking each sub-grid
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i+=root(n))
            for (int j=0;j<n;j+=root(n))
                grids=checkGrids(n, mat ,i, j);
    }
    rows=checkRows(n, mat);
    cols=checkColumns(n, mat);
    if ((rows==1)&&(cols==1)&&(grids==1))
        printValidSolution();
    else
        printBadSolution();
    return 0;
}
void printOpenMessageForSodokoSize()
{
    printf("Please enter the size of your soduko:\n");
}
void printOpenMessageForSodokoSolution()
{
    printf("Please enter your solution:\n");
}
void printValidSolution()
{
    printf("Valid solution!");
}
void printBadSolution()
{
    printf("Bad solution!");
}
int root(int a) //not using math library on purpose.
{
    if (a==0)
        return 0;
    if (a<0)
        return -1;
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        if (i*i==a)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
void bubbleSort(int arr[],int n) //sorting an array
{
    int swap;
    for (int i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                swap=arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=swap;
            }
        }
}
int compareTo(int arr[],int n) //check if 2 arrays are equal
{
    int equal=1; //return 1 if equals 0 if not
    int arr2[n]; //building the array to compare to
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr2[i]=i+1;
    while(equal)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            equal=(arr[i]==arr2[i]);
    }
    return equal;
}
int checkRows(int n, int mat[][n]) //checking the rows
{
    int rows=1;
    int arr[n];
    while (rows)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                arr[j]=mat[i][j]; //creating an array for each row
        bubbleSort(arr, n); // sort it
        rows=compareTo(arr, n); // compare it
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
int checkColumns(int n, int mat[][n])
{
    int columns=1;
    int arr[n];
    while (columns)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                arr[j]=mat[j][i]; //creating an array for each column
        bubbleSort(arr, n); // sort it
        columns=compareTo(arr, n); //compare it
        }
    }
    return columns;
}
int checkGrids(int n, int mat[][n], int sRow, int sCol)
{
    int grids=1;
    int arr[n];
    int index=0;
    for (int i=sRow;i<root(n);i++)
        for (int j=sCol;j<root(n);j++)
        {
            arr[index]=mat[i][j]; //creating an array for each grid
            index++;
        }
    bubbleSort(arr, n); // sort it
    grids=compareTo(arr, n); //compare it
    return grids;
}
```

Comment: So what's going wrong? Does it crash, does it produce wrong output? What happens?

Comment: I tried to enter a valid 4*4 solution and the program won't print anything, right or wrong.

Comment: Read this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: _"I don't know why, but my program doesn't work and I need help"_, so what does it do? which part is not functioning well? have you debugged the checking procedure? could you narrow the potential glitchy parts?

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough. I enter any solution, valid or not, and the program continuing running without printing any message or ending.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` uses buffered output which means that anything you `printf` does not appear on the terminal until a `\n` is printed or an `fflush(stdout)` is executed.

Try the following:

```
void printValidSolution()
{
    printf("Valid solution!\n"); // new line added
}
void printBadSolution()
{
    printf("Bad solution!\n"); // new line added
}
```

Another problem

```
int compareTo(int arr[],int n) //check if 2 arrays are equal
{
    int equal=1; //return 1 if equals 0 if not
    int arr2[n]; //building the array to compare to
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr2[i]=i+1;
    while(equal)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            equal=(arr[i]==arr2[i]);
    }
    return equal;
}
```

This function will never terminate if `arr[n - 1] == arr2[n - 1]` because there is nothing in the `while` loop that changes the arrays, so the `for` loop will always eventually set `equal` to the result of the last comparison. Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure what the function is supposed to do, so I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I tried this but it won't help.. I enter any solution, valid or not, and the program continuing running without printing any message or ending.

Comment: @Ro168 if the program is running without terminating rather than just not printing anything, you should probably mention it in the question.

Comment: @Ro168 I've spotted one infinite loop - see amended answer.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help and I am sorry for the lack of my explanation.  The ComapreTo function is comparing every array containing each row, column and box to a sorted array from 1-n, If both of the arrays are equal, I know for sure that every number is showing only once and the solution is valid. I tried to fix the function according to the problem you noticed by adding another condition to the 'while' loop - now it's "while((equal)||(i==n))' ,but still the program is running without terminating. I've spent several hours trying to debugg and I desperate for help. Thanks again